# when i send a message for live notification is shows the error: no connection can be made

Tags: php

My `route.php` page contain,

```
Route::get('/socket', 'socketController@index');
Route::post('/sendmessage', 'socketController@sendMessage');
Route::get('/writemessage', 'socketController@writemessage');
```

---

my `socketcontroller` page

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use LRedis;

class socketController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('AdminPanel.bladefiles.socket');
    }

    public function writemessage()
    {
        return view('AdminPanel.bladefiles.writemessage');
    }

    public function sendMessage()
    {
        $redis = LRedis::connection();
        $redis->publish('message', Request::input('message'));
        return redirect('AdminPanel.bladefiles.writemessage');
    }

}
```

---

in my `socket.blade.php` file I written this code, when I redirect to `sendmessage()` I got an error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- general form elements -->
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Live Notification</h3>
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <!-- form start -->
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" >
                            <div id="messages" ></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script>
                    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
                    socket.on('message', function (data) {
                        $("#messages").append("<p>" + data + "</p>");
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure redis is correctly installed in your machine .
>   In your console  try below

```
redis-cli ping
```

You should see "PONG"

Check this link 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51